# Private are mapping of unichar in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, unicode

In NSEvent in key down event it has characters property and it has a character like 'a' as the first character when you hit a key 'a'.
When I hit down-arrow key I get 63233 as a decimal expression of the first character.
I wonder what is the number and I found that 63233 = 0xF701 is in a private area in Unicode according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_(Unicode) .

What I want to know is how and where they are defined. Is there any document which lists up all the character mappings used in Cocoa??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [NSText class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html) contains the character mappings of common command and modifier keys.  The Down Arrow key is specifically defined as `NSDownTextMovement    = 0x16`.  A more complete list can be found in HIToolbox, a sub-framework of Carbon in Events.h

Comment: What's the relationship between NSDownTextMovement(0x16) and the character I get in NSEvent which is 63233(0xF701) ??

Comment: @ShuSuzuki The `characters` property is an NSString.  I think you logged a memory address and not an actual character

Comment: I get it as a 'unichar' character. Not the address. I did like this.
NSLog( @"%d", [[event characters] characterAtIndex:0] )

Comment: Thanks. This is what I exactly wanted. Looks NSEvent.h defines it.